# How can I parse out information I need out of column one with no delimiters in the html I'm scraping from

Tags: pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, jupyter-notebook

I'm scraping data from this website to get the name of the beer, the brewery, the alcohol percentage, and average rating. The issue I'm running into is the beer name, brewery, and alcohol rating are all in one column. I would like these values to be separate but the html is showing no delimiters that I would be able to use to parse the data. Here is my code:

```
from splinter import Browser
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import pandas as pd

req = Request(
    url='https://www.beeradvocate.com/beer/top-rated/us/mi/', 
    headers={'User-Agent': 'Chrome/5.0'}
)
webpage = urlopen(req).read()
print(webpage)

beer_df = pd.read_html(webpage)
beer_df[0].head()
```

[html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7t9u.png)
[df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/St3vD.png)

Comment: Hi Nat! Welcome to StackOverflow. It seems like the data is stored in a slightly strange way, that pandas isn't able to automatically parse. It seems like you're going to have to do the parsing manually, as it doesn't include the newlines in the output df, but does include it in the raw HTML